# what the difference between 24/30/60 frames per second in the context of a 7 day/night time lapse video?

Tags: time-lapse, gopro, fps

So I am looking to record a time lapse video with my used GoPro Hero 7 black that will capture 7 days and nights worth of video of my sprouts under the grow lights, with the final product being a 12 second video. I have been told it depends on whether I want to do 24fps, 30 or 60, but I do not know what the qualitative difference would be as I am a complete beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you record a timelapse video over a long period of time, you usually only take a single image, then pause for a specific length of time, then take the next image.

Frames per second are usually only considered when you choose to play back these images afterwards.

In the GoPro Hero 7 Black [manual](https://gopro.com/content/dam/help/hero7-black/manuals/HERO7Black_UM_ENG_REVC.pdf), on page 108 it explains how to set the delay time on a time-lapse.

If you want to record over 7 days and nights, to create a 12 second video at 30 frames per second, you would calculate it like this:

> A 12 second video at a playback speed of 30 frames per second = 12 x
> 30 = 360 frames in total.
>
> So recording over 7 days = 7 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes = 10,080
> minutes in total.
>
> 10080 / 360 = 28 minutes between each image taken
>
> 28 * 360 = 10,080 minutes total

You can always choose to take images more frequently (I would, but this requires more storage space).
You can always dispose of them if you don't want to use them, but it gives you the option to either make your time-lapse longer if you decide to later, or to use a higher playback frame rate.

In terms of using other playback frame rates - if you record at 24 or 60 fps, you would need these interval times:

> 12 * 24fps = 288 frames needed
>
> 12 * 60fps = 720 frames needed
>
> 10080 / 288 = 35 minute interval
>
> 10080 / 720 = 14 minute interval

Other tips:

- Use a tripod.
- Test the lighting conditions and think about exposure levels on the camera.
- Fixed exposure is better than variable so long as it is correctly set.

Comment: I am truly a noob, could you expand more by what you mean with "exposure levels"?

Comment: You don’t want the sensitivity to light adjusting constantly in your time lapse as it will cause flickering. If your source of light in the video is constant, it’s less of an issue, but if there is natural light in the video (eg a window in the room), the light levels will change over the course of the day, so you need to decide what level of exposure to use in your time lapse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_(photography)